# Codeigniter remove index.php and prefix the URL with www

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I want to remove the default `index.php` that auto comes with `Codeigniter`.

I've been able to remove that with this code

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

`example.com/index.php/blog` can now be accessed by `example.com/blog`

I later wanted to prefix the `URL` with a `www` i.e `example.com/blog` should redirect to `www.example.com/blog` with these rewrite rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

After adding this code above to the end of my `.htaccess` file, it began to misbehave.

If I enter `www.example.com/blog` into a `URL` bar it works fine but if I enter `example.com/blog` it redirects to `www.example.com/index.php/blog`

What I'm I doing wrong?

I want `example.com/blog` to redirect to `www.example.com/blog`

**Note:** I am using the `Codeigniter` framework.

**Added:** This code is just on top of the previous ones I have up. Maybe this is it's problem please HELP!!!

```
RewriteCond $1 !^{index\.php|[assests/images/themes/fonts/style/scripts/js/install]|robot\.txt|favicon\.ico}
```

Comment: Put !www -> www rule before one that rewrites `index.php`. I.e first add `www` if needed, than strip `index.php`.

Comment: I understood there was wrong order of rules in file. Change the order of rules. First write down one for `www`, than bellow, write down one for `index.php`.

Comment: Or use [this one](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/). It has everything you need here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much tricks and following the [post](http://www.farinspace.com/codeigniter-htaccess-file/) given by @Tpojka I was able to come up with this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# no www -> www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This guy was my problem

```
RewriteCond $1 !^{index\.php|[assests/images/themes/fonts/style/scripts/js/install]|robot\.txt|favicon\.ico}
```

I would need help on how to exclude folders and some files like `robot.txt` file like I tried in the malfunctioning line.

Comment: I am not sure for those curly braces. Try `()` instead `{}`. After that you should be able to put that line before `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`.

Comment: @Tpojka you is genius!!! It worked like "magic" Thanks for the answer. I would have made this a new question but I don't have a title for it so I cud mark it as answered by you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This did not work. If a user self puts in `example.com/` in the `URL` bar, it will not redirect the user to `www.example.com`

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete .htaccess file which I use personally:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
    RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Comment: This will not force the `URL` to be prefixed with `www`